# Access rel attribute using this keyword javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please check the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F6rtm/1/) , the rel attribute in the alert comes out as 'undefined' :

```
var ItemTypeArray = $('input[name^=ItemType]:checked').map(function(){


alert(this.id + '  , r= ' + this.rel);  

return this.rel + '--' + this.value;

}).get().join(",");
```

Also , this function gives a string , but I need an array to be constructed to post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such attribute called `rel` on an `input` (there is on a `link` tag however). You should really use `data` attributes instead:

```
<input id="SOLD[1]" value="1" name="ItemType[1]" type="radio" data-rel="1">
<input id="PURCHASED[1]" value="2" name="ItemType[1]" type="radio" checked="checked" data-rel="1">
```

Then you can do:

```
var ItemTypeArray = $('input[name^=ItemType]:checked').map(function () {
    alert(this.id + '  , r= ' + $(this).data("rel"));
    return $(this).data("rel") + '--' + this.value;
}).get().join(",");
```

Or to return what you stated in comments (an array), you can do:

```
var ItemTypeArray = [];

$('input[name^=ItemType]:checked').each(function () {
    ItemTypeArray.push(this.id + ' = ' + $(this).data("rel"));
});
```

See [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/F6rtm/6/)

Comment: thanks a lot sir, but how to get an array using this code , this code returns a string ...but i need an array like this : SOLD[1] = 1 or SOLD[1] = 2 , in which the value of the array element is the rel property.

Comment: sir ,if i need in my code : $Sold = $_POST['SOLD'] , and on echoing it i need : foreach($Sold as $ItemID=>$Type) echo 'item id = ' . $ItemID . ' , type ='. $Type;

Answer (score 1):

I just included jquery and modified your code as follows.  Use `$(this).attr('rel')` instead of `this.rel`

```
    var ItemTypeArray = $('input[name^=ItemType]:checked').map(function () {
        alert(this.id + '  , r= ' + $(this).attr('rel'));
        return this.rel + '--' + this.value;
}).get().join(",");
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F6rtm/2/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $(this).attr("rel")
```

this will get you an attribute value named 'rel'